# Text between less than and greater than not output PHP

Tags: php

i use (str_replace) function to replace ##ID## in youtube url with this regular expression : `(?P<id>[a-z-A-Z_0-9]+)`
so i use this code to do this :

```
<?php
  $urlbase = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=##ID##';
  $lastchange = str_replace('##ID##', '(<id>[a-z-A-Z_0-9]+)', $urlbase);
  echo $lastchange;
?>
```

i get the output in the browser like this : `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=(?P[a-z-A-Z_0-9]+)`, its looks like `<id>` not show up !

i try this simple code :

```
<?php
 echo "This is my <id>";
?>
```

but i just get `this is my` in the browser !

What's the probleme ? and how i can fix it , thanks

Comment: View the source. `<id>` in the browser won't display because it will think it is an element.

Comment: inspect the page, its probably reading at least part of that as some html tag.

Comment: If you want to display the `<` and `>` use http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php.

Answer (score 0):

is being interpreted as HTML so your browser is parsing it and since it is not a renderable element, it shows nothing. Try:

```
<?php
  echo "This is my &lt;id&gt;
?>
```

As for the str_replace, it's doing exactly what the function is supposed to be doing. If you're looking to use regular expressions in string replacements, use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the line:

```
$lastchange = str_replace('##ID##', '(<id>[a-z-A-Z_0-9]+)', $urlbase);
```

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) does not use regex.

You will need [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$pattern = '(<id>[a-z-A-Z_0-9]+)'
$replacement = '##ID##'
$string = $urlbase
$lastchange = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Also `<` and `>` are [html entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) which means they are reserved chars for HTML they have some special meanings if you want to show them then you must use there entity name eg `&lt;` and `&gt;` in your case respectively.

```
<?php
   echo " echo "This is my &lt;id&gt;";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The tag <id> is being removed by your browser. It is really there if you watch the source code. Maybe you should try:

```
  $urlbase = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=##ID##';
  $lastchange = str_replace('##ID##', '(<id>[a-z-A-Z_0-9]+)', $urlbase);
  echo urlencode( $lastchange );
```